# Single Sign-On in iOS App with Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, authentication, air, single-sign-on, facebook-authentication

I am trying to integrate Facebook SSO on my iOS Game that I'm developing using Flash (with AIR).

I'm using the only tutorial that I've found (it's a pretty good one):
http://www.saumitrabhave.com/2011/10/facebook-single-sign-on-for-air-ios.html

I've gone so far, and implemented the things there, but I'm stuck with getting the access token back to the app.

In the tutorial, the invoke method (which is called when Facebook authorization is complete and we're back to the app) is implemented as follows:

```
protected function onInvoke(e:InvokeEvent):void{  
 var str:String = e.arguments[0];
 if(str && str.indexOf("fb"+APP_ID+"://") != -1 )
 ...
```

`e.arguments` is always an empty array and because of this, `str` is undefined. What can cause this behavior?

Thanks,
Can.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the solution (I've been trying to figure out for hours). The invoke method is somehow called twice, and I was just checking the first one (without realizing that there even is a second call) and because it wasn't working, I was terminating the app without checking anything else afterwards.

For future reference: Invoke event may be called twice, the first one doesn't have the auth token sent, but the second one has.